# Removing full screen event listener in ngOnDestroy

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

Can't remove fullscreenchange event listener in ngOnDestroy Angular 6

I've tried calling the .removeEventListener() in ngOnDestroy which doesn't remove the events. I have also tried calling the removeEventListeners in a function after a 10 second timeout, and the events still continue to be triggered after.

imports

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, HostBinding, Inject, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
```

Component code

```
elem: any;
constructor(private framesService: FramesService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.elem = this.document.documentElement;
    this.document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', this.onFullscreenChange.bind(this));
    this.document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', this.onFullscreenChange.bind(this));
 }

onFullscreenChange(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Fullscreen event fired');
}

onViewFrame() {
    if (this.elem.requestFullscreen) { // Chrome
      this.elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { // Firefox
      this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.document.removeEventListener('fullscreenchange', this.onFullscreenChange.bind(this));
    this.document.removeEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', this.onFullscreenChange.bind(this));
}
```

The onViewFrame() function is tied to a click event from a button on the page.

Every time this component is constructed, the events are added, but they are never removed. So if this component is loaded 3 times during a browsing session on the page, it will trigger the console.log three times every time full screen is initiated or the ESC key is used to exit full screen. Would like the events to be removed upon leaving so that they may be re-registered properly the next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.onFullscreenChange.bind(this)` creates a new reference to that function.  You need to pass the same reference to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

```
elem: any;
fsEventHandler: any = this.onFullscreenChange.bind(this); // <- Here

ngOnInit() {
  this.elem = this.document.documentElement;
  this.document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', this.fsEventHandler);
  this.document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', this.fsEventHandler);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.document.removeEventListener('fullscreenchange', this.fsEventHandler);
    this.document.removeEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', this.fsEventHandler);
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#Matching_event_listeners_for_removal) for more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Angular you can use `RxJS` to achieve the same behavior.

You can create Observable using `fromEvent`

```
fromEvent(this.document, 'fullscreenchange');
```

To trigger some function you need to add `.pipe()` with `tap` operator, to activate it you also need to subscribe to it. Also save the subscription to be able to unsubscribe inside of `ngOnDestroy()`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.elem = this.document.documentElement;
    console.log(this.document);
    this.fullScreen = fromEvent(this.document, 'fullscreenchange').pipe(
        tap(this.onFullscreenChange.bind(this))
      ).subscribe();
 }

onFullscreenChange(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Fullscreen event fired');
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.fullScreen.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Good idea, didn't even think about this route. Thanks!